# How to set default schema of kdeveloper as dark vim for all text editor?

Tags: themes, kdevelop

I try to set my kdevelop editors as dark theme. I manage to switch one editor to dark by clicking Editor->View->schema-> Solarised (dark). I have set the theme for every single editor. Is it possible to set the default schema as dark for all editors once?

Comment: Not sure if such an option exists!